# comma separated auto complete with jquery auto complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to implement auto complete via jquery auto complete plugin.A simple auto complete works for me. I am not able to achieve  comma separated auto complete .

Please help me with where I am going wrong.

My jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$.getJSON('/releases/new.json', function() {      
alert("inside getJson"); 
alert(data1); 
$('#release_tester_tokens').autocomplete({source:names,multiple: true});  
});
});
```

Thanks,
Ramya.

Comment: I achieved this by giving the same code in a function and calling it from my view file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See if this [walk-through](http://codeasp.net/articles/asp-net/212/using-jquery-autocomplete-in-asp-net) helps. It includes the following code which allows the user to **enter multiple search terms separated by commas**:

```
$("#<%= txtMultipleName.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("AutoComplete.ashx", {
            term: extractLast(request.term)
        }, response);
    },
    search: function () {
        // custom minLength
        var term = extractLast(this.value);
        if (term.length < 1) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    focus: function () {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join(", ");
        return false;
    }
});
function split(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
}
function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}
```

There is also plenty of information on the [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple) page.

Comment: It would be better if u give us live example link of your code :)

Answer (score 4):

In your example you are accessing variables that are not even defined and never any of the results from your getJSON call. In JSON a comma separated list is actually an array (if it is in [] brackets). If it is a string just use a [String split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to create the source array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $.getJSON('/releases/new.json', function(data) {
        $('#release_tester_tokens').autocomplete({
            source: data.list,
            multiple: true
        });  
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Daff, Thanks a lot for answering me . I am passing the source variable via the view code : :javascript
   names = #{Release.user_names.to_json}

Comment: Don't do stuff like that in your views, try to keep it all in the JS file. Are you using a JavaScript view renderer?

Comment: Hi Daff, I have the javascript view renderer in my controller as  @@user_names||= User.all.map(&:name)
.  respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @release }
      format.json { render :json =>{ :data=>@@user_names } }
    end
Since it didn't work for me I went for the latter method.

Comment: Hi Daff, I tried having it as an array using split function. Its displayed just like aaa,bbb when displayed in the console. Also if I give data.split the autocomplete is not working. only if I give source:data autocomplete is working.But multi select option is not working.Please help me out here

Comment: Well the console probably logs it correct like an array. Autocomplete doesn't have a multiple option though. Check out source of the demo for multi select (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple)

Comment: It would be better if u give us live example link of your code :)