# search city with auto complete with comma separated state and country

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I want to search and display city list autocomplete feature from mydatabase with comma separated state and country  name like this.[image]

Comment: here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716811/comma-separated-auto-complete-with-jquery-auto-complete

Answer (score 0):

You're not asking for a typical search where the input begins at the beginning of the string being searched.

Your example shows a user typing in a sub-string of the actual data. The search built in to the combo box will never find it because it searches from left-to-right (in English anyway) and therefore is looking in the "D"s.

You'll need to add code to the keypress event to execute a substring-based search.

In VB you could use INSTR().

Hope this helps.